# MySQL finding way in graph of stations that are on different roads

Tags: mysql

I have one little problem.

In my database i have tables:

```
postaje (id (INT A_I), ime_postaje (VARCHAR), latitude (DOUBLE), longitude (Double))

proge (ID (INT A_I), ime (VARCHAR))

postaje_proge (ID (INT A_I), ID_postaje (INT), ID_proge (INT), stevilo (INT))
```

`postaje` are points (bus stops) on map with longitude and latitude, `proge` are roads that contains that points and `postaje_proge` is connection between points and roads (that we know on what roads stations are. `stevilo` is index of point on road...)
For example we have in `postaje` IDs from 1 to 9. in `proge` IDs 1 (ime aka name of road A) and 2 (B). So in `postaje_proge` we get:

```
[ID, ID_postaje, ID_proge, stevilo ] 
[0,  1,          1,        1] 
[1,  2,          1,        2]
[2,  3,          1,        3]
[3,  4,          1,        4]
[4,  5,          1,        5]
[5,  6,          2,        1]
[6,  7,          2,        2]
[7,  2,          2,        3]
[8,  3,          2,        4]
[9,  8,          2,        5]
[10, 9,          2,        6]
```

Now I would like to get Result that returns all points between 1 and 9 in a correct order (so IDs `postaje` should be this: 1, 2, 3, 8, 9 ). My English is not really good but I hope you will understand what I wanna do :D

[image]

Comment: What if there are multiple routes between the start and end points?

Comment: for now lets say that they are just 2 :P :D if there is a solution for more than 2 even better :D